# Powershell List Process in Docker Windows Container Produces Empty List

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I need to get the process id of a dotnet application running in a windows container in order to attach a debugger to it, but when I try to list the processess, I get an empty list.

```
PS > docker exec -it --privileged elated_swartz powershell -Command Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Select-Object ProcessId, CommandLine

ProcessId CommandLine
--------- -----------
```

PSVersion 5.1.15063.483

Docker Client:
Version: 17.06.0-ce
API version: 1.30
Go version: go1.8.3
Git commit: 02c1d87
Built: Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
OS/Arch: windows/amd64

Docker Server:
Version: 17.06.0-ce
API version: 1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version: go1.8.3
Git commit: 02c1d87
Built: Fri Jun 23 22:19:00 2017
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *nix:

```
docker top <container>
```

In Windows
Using CMD:

```
docker exec <container> tasklist
```

Using Powershell:

```
docker exec <container> powershell get-process
```